# Adding list items to a page tactically

Tags: html, css

I have about 2000 items that I want to add my page. They are right now in alphabetical order in a word doc, and I want to add them in a list sort of manner. Since there are so many of them, and I basically right now am adding each of them one by one I needed to know if there is a quicker way I am missing? Please let me know if so.

Comment: Find an replace; paste as rich text and copy code

Comment: Find and replace? Please specify. Keep in mind that these items need to look the same symmetrically in the list. Right now i am adding each item in a LI. And its painful.

Comment: Replace `\n` (or `\r\n` or `\r`, depending on your OS and application being used) with `</li>\n<li>` (where `\n` is a new line). Alternatively replace with `\n<li>` as `<li>` doesn't require a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've got some real trick out here go to [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php), Copy Paste the list of words, select all and make it as a list and press **submit** now copy paste all the items from **"Source output from post"**

Answer (score 0):

- Open your dreamweaver and the page you are working on.
- Paste the texts
- Select All
- Go Properties Panel Find the list button then click it. It should convert all the texts to list items
  [image]

Comment: I dont use Dreamweaver... Are there any other ways?

Comment: That is insanely awesome. Just saved me roughly 10-15 hours. Thanks!